# netflow version 5 only ingress or both ingress as well as egress

Tags: networking

netflow version 5 documentation says it supports only ingress,but on gns3 I am able to get both type of data(ingress as well as egress).Have I understood something wrong?Please help.

Comment: To what documentation are you referring? I know of no such restriction on Netflow v5, but unless you provide some reference to what you're talking about there's no possible way for us to give you meaningful answers

Comment: Have a look at this...it is saying in a NOTE: Egress is only available in Cisco NetFlow v9 and not NetFlowv5 http://www.paessler.com/knowledgebase/en/topic/20823-what-are-the-right-netflow-settings-ingress-vs-egress

Answer (score 1):

Check the date of issue of your netflow documentation and compare to date of issue of your cisco IOS.

Formerly, only ingress netflow was available independently of neflow version. Later the egress option became available on some platforms.

This is bacause netflow accounting was closely coupled with data forwarding and output interface as well as next-hop was determined during netflow process. Netlow table was treated as a cache of flow processing: only first packet of a flow needs route and ACL lookup - others use egress interface and next-hop saved in the flow record.

Thus, you could not use "egress" in the past since when egress interface determined, traffic has already been accounted.

Now, with CEF and hardware accelerated ACLs, netflow cache is not needed as forwarding
acceleration approach. Thus, a platform can perform forwarding first and make decision whether to account packet or not, depending on egress interface.

Comment: Thanks Veniamin.It is right that ingress or egress can be configured on any device independent of netflow version ,but when that data is exported to a collector,the netflow version 5 exported data is not having any field which will tell whether it is ingress or egress data.So,it is not possible to handle the data.On the other hand,netflow version 9 is having a direction field in each of its pdu to give that information.Please enlighten me on this.

Comment: @AvinashJha I do not see the problem here.  Egress and Ingress directives are just a filter deciding whether to account packet or not. In order to get real data flow direction Source and Destination Interface numbers can be used. They are both represented in Netflow 5. I can not effectively consult you about Netflow 9 since did not work with It.